# How to share anything?

Tags: android, share, intentfilter

As a learning exercise, I'm writing an app that has a android.intent.action.SEND intent. I want to be able to have it send anything I can come up with a filename for, but all the examples I see of defining such apps are specific to images in the mediastore, ringtones in the ringtone manager, etc. I don't want to enumerate every possible algorithm I've found by google searches for converting a Uri to a file. I'd like a generic solution. I've seen an OPENABLE category which sounds promising, but I still haven't seen a generic solution for discovery of the underlying filename. Is there one?

I just want this thing to upload whatever content it is handed to a php script that implements a POST method for doing file uploads. I don't see any reason to restrict it to images or video, or something like that, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make it work for any random file some other app wants to share.

Comment: Are you trying to *call* `startActivity()` with an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, or are you trying to implement an activity that *responds to* an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`?

Comment: I'm responding to ACTION_SEND. Whatever content I get I want to upload to a web server. I've read up on ContentResolver and ParcelFileDescriptor, so I think (though I haven't tried yet) I have a way to read the data, but I'm looking for a file name to use, and can't find anything like that (unless maybe toString() human readable description happens to be a file name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking for a file name to use

There is no guarantee that there is a file name to use. Particularly if the scheme is `content://`, it is quite likely that there is no file name, because in some cases there is no file (e.g., the data is a BLOB in a database).

Off the cuff, I'd use an algorithm like this: if the scheme is `content://` and `getLastPathSegment()` on the `Uri` returns an integer, generate a filename; otherwise, use `getLastPathSegment()`. That should cover `content://`, `file://`, and `http://` schemes reasonably well, and I can't think of any other scheme you're likely to encounter in an `ACTION_SEND`-handling activity.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl. It does seem like that is likely to be the best I can do. Seems odd that there doesn't seem to be any kind of intent filter I can use to say "just things that are files, please". Thanks.

Comment: @user1160711: Oh, if you truly want only things with the `file://` scheme, use a `<data>` element in your `<intent-filter>` to limit by scheme. I interpreted statements like "I just want this thing to upload whatever content it is handed" to mean that you just want this thing to upload whatever content it is handed, which does not imply only files.

Comment: Yea, only getting file:// doesn't work. For example, pictures from the gallery are clearly files (you can find 'em in a file browser), but if you do a share action from the gallery app, you definitely don't get a file:// Uri, even though there is a file buried back there somewhere.